# Copy data from production database back to SqlLocalDb

Tags: sql, localdb

I've had to reinstall my OS so have lost the development Sql LocalDb instance of my website's database.

However, I do have the live database on my production server.

I want to recreate my LocalDb from the live database.

How do I do this?

I used to transfer data between production and development (and vice versa) using backup and restore but my new clean installation of windows does not have SQL Express anymore.

I guess I could generate scripts but I'm not sure if that would successfully create a localdb instance.

Comment: Why can't you reinstall SQL Express?

Comment: Yes, I could do that. However as LocalDB is Microsoft's 'recommended database engine' I thought I would see how I could work within those constraints. However it looks like I'll need to at least download/install Management Studio

Comment: Installing Management Studio allowed me to use the backup/restore method. However, I do wonder how this could be done from within Visual Studio.